# first row of the resultset of a stored procedure as Column header in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to the use first row of the result set of a stored procedure as Column header in SSRS, will it be possible.

For example if the stored procedure returns data like this:

```
 Germany Oncology 100
 India  Dentist  200
 Russia Doctor   300
```

I want the column headers as

```
  Germany Oncology 100
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expression of Column Header of the Tablix, use `=First(Fields!Column1.Value, "DataSet")`. Do it for each column and mention the corresponding column